# Javascript set Date object from multiple strings

Tags: javascript, string, date

I'm really new to making dates in JavaScript, and I have a super interesting situation where I need to create a `Date` object in Javascript, but all the pieces of time from an API are in different places i.e.:

```
"Thursday": {
  "times": {
    "currently_open": false,
    "status": "open",
    "hours": [
      {
        "from": "8:00am",
        "to": "1:00am"
      }
    ]
  },
  "date": "2018-07-12",
  "rendered": "8:00am - 1:00am"
},
```

So somehow, I need to combine all the elements from the `date`, with the `hours[0].from` time. But  because the actual times appear in a string  as `8:00am` in this example, I'm not really sure what I have to do to convert that into a time that JavaScript can read.

This is probably pretty stupid, but what I've tried to create a new Date object by combining values from the API data like this:

`openTime = new Date( Thursday.date + 'T' + Thursday.times.hours[0].from + 'Z' );`

It doesn't work. lol. Does anyone have any suggestions? Basically I tried creating a string by adding all the pieces together. Any help would be amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your time / date format is quite unique, you have to parse it manually:

```js
const Thursday = {
  "times": {
    "currently_open": false,
    "status": "open",
    "hours": [
       {
        "from": "8:00am",
        "to": "1:00am"
        }
    ]
  },
  "date": "2018-07-12",
  "rendered": "8:00am - 1:00am"
}

let [hours, minutes] = Thursday.times.hours[0].from.split(":").map(el => parseInt(el));

 if (Thursday.times.hours[0].from.includes("pm"))
  hours += 12;

const date = new Date(...Thursday.date.split("-").map((n, i) => n - (i === 1)), hours, minutes);
console.log(date.toString())
```

Comment: @JonasW. right on! Thanks you! This solution worked like a champ! I had to adapt it a little because my I'm not setup to preprocess ES6 yet.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Using Moment.js:

```js
const time = Thursday.hours[0].from;

const match = /(.*)((a|p)m)/.exec(time);

const hourMin = match[1].length === 4 ? `0${match[1]}` : match[1];

const amPm = match[2];

const openTime = moment(`${Thursday.date} ${hourMin} ${amPm}`).toDate();
```

Comment: An answer should not depend on a library that is not tagged or mentioned in the OP. Your use of moment.js is also sub-optimal, you should tell the parser the format of the string it has to parse, otherwise you're just hoping the parser heuristics are what you want. The *amPm* logic would be simpler as `Thursday.hours[0].from.slice(-2)`.